# Acumatica - Unposted Journal transactions

Tags: c#, acumatica

I programmatically create a credit memo and then i release by `ARDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(rebateRelease, false);` and i got this error.
`{"Error: Another process has updated the 'ARRegister' record. Your changes will be lost."}`.

The effect of this error is in the journal transaction, the created journal transaction is having a unposted status. Please check the images thanks.
[Unposted Journal Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoozU.png), [Closed Credit Memo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcDj9.png), [Error in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wwuz.png),  [Suggestion 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIA6M.png)

MY CODE BELOW:

```
   `ARInvoice arInvoice = new ARInvoice();
            arInvoice.DocType = "CRM";
            arInvoice.CustomerID = loan.BAccountID;
            arInvoice.CustomerLocationID = loan.CustomerLocation;
            arInvoice.DocDesc = "";
            arInvoice.OpenDoc = true;
            arInvoice.Released = false;
            arInvoice.Hold = false;
            arInvoice.Status = "B";
            if (arSetup.RequireControlTotal == true)
            {
                arInvoice.CuryOrigDocAmt = amount;
            }
            arInvoice = ARGraph.Document.Update(arInvoice);
            ARGraph.Actions.PressSave();
 ARTran arTran = new ARTran();
            arTran.RefNbr = arInvoice.RefNbr;
            arTran.LineNbr = 1;
            arTran.SortOrder = 1;
            arTran.TranDesc = description;
            arTran.AccountID = accountID;
            arTran.SubID = subID;
            arTran.Qty = 1;
            arTran.TaxCategoryID = other.TaxCategoryID;
            arTran.CuryExtPrice = amount;
            arTran.Released = false;
            ARGraph.Transactions.Insert(arTran);
            ARGraph.Actions.PressSave();
            rebateRelease.Add(arInvoice);
            ARDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(rebateRelease, false);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the last few lines to this...

```
rebateRelease.Add(ARGraph.Document.Current);
ARDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(rebateRelease, false);
```

My guess your issue is that you saved the graph which updated your arInvoice record and you are still using the old arInvoice record through that object. You need the updated value after you did the press save.

Also to save some overhead you can just save once before you send the doc to release. No need to save after the `ARGraph.Document.Update(arInvoice)` line.

Comment: I already tried your suggestion but I still got that error. check my updated screenshots thank you!

Comment: can you update the code you are using that uses the current ARRegister document? this will help to solve your problem as the problem is most likly you are not passing the persisted ARRegister to the ReleaseDoc process which you are passing through rebateRelease. I think the ReleaseDoc needs an ARRegister when you are adding the ARInvoice to the list... will that even work? (based on your current code sample)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIA6M.png  this is the updated code. I tried to use your recommendation but still that error exist. THANKS